# Visual Studio Code Intellisense stops working after file save (python)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Basically I'm having an issue with intellisense where after I save the python file I'm working on autocomplete just seems to crash in exact scenarios it works in before saving the file to my computer. I have tried restarting program/computer, re-installing both python and visual studio code, as well as opening in admin mode. I've spent a couple of hours looking this up on the internet with no successful results. The only extension I am using is the Python extension by Don Jayamanne.
Thanks!